# C# method getting invoked twice on Enter Key

Tags: c#

I am in the process of creating a `POS` system using C# and I have an issue with Textbox to read bar-code.

I want to read bar-code from the scanner either when the textbox has focus or not. Again I want the textbox to have capability to search for product manually that is user input the bar-code and then press the enter key the bar code captured should be used to query MySQL.

I have used this code to read bar-code from scanner when my textbox has focus or not but the problem is that when I want to search for product manually using enter key the method to query db is getting invoked twice and I don't understand why. Need help to prevent the function from getting invoked twice as well as provide functionality to search bar-code on enter and when textbox has no focus that is get input from scanner

```
 private string _barcode = "";
 protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)//read when no focus
 {
            char c = (char)keyData;

            if (char.IsNumber(c))
                _barcode += c;

            if (c == (char)Keys.Return)
            {
                
                   read_scanner(_barcode);
                    _barcode = "";
                
                 
            }

            return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
 }
```

This my code to search manually

```
private void txtbarcode_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
   {
      // onQuery = true;
      read_scanner(txtbarcode.Text);
   }
}
```

And here is my method which is getting invoked twice when I press enter key

```
Product product;
public void read_scanner(string barcode)//this method is getting invoked twice when i search product manually
{
           // 
           
            product = HibernateDao.getRecord("from Product u where u.barcode='"+barcoded+"'");
            if (product != null)
            {
                
                pos_datagrid.Rows.Add(barcode, product.product_name, product.product_desc, null, "1", null, product_Cost);
                
            }
            else
            {
               AppUtil.showErrorBox("Invalid bar code!!");
                
            }

           
}
```

Comment: Just a sanity check, are you sure tje read_scanner method is invoked twice by *the same event instance* ? Or is the KeyDown event raised more than once ?

Comment: I've just copied your code into an empty Win Forms project with a text box (txtbarcode) and button. When I TAB focus between the button and textbox the `ProcessCmdKey` method fires every time no matter what the focus is. But the KeyDown event of the textbox never fires. The `ProcessCmdKey` method passes the key to its parent control, so no matter which control has focus it should always fire which is what I am seeing. I'm wondering if your KeyDown event is also firing even though mine isn't. Try removing the KeyDown event for a moment and see if it still works with and without focus.

Comment: If that doesn't solve the problem, I've also seen other people mention a bug in some cases where the KeyUp event fires twice. They have solved those problems by using the KeyUp event instead. You should also try setting `e.Handled = true;` in the KeyUp/KeyDown event.

Comment: @Daniel I dont understand what u are saying concerning e.Handled=true

Comment: Yes, but your read _scanner method can be called by both the ProcessCmdKey method and the txtbarcode_KeyDown method. You need to work out if one of those methods is calling it twice and if so, which one. Or if both methods are being called meaning they are calling it once each at the same time.

Comment: @Daniel ProcessCmdKey is getting fired when i use key press event

Comment: @Daniel try put a msg.box only on that read_scanner method and see its getting invoked twice

Comment: @Sidewinder94 ProcessCmdKey is getting fired when i use KeyDown event,  try put a msg.box only on that read_scanner method and see its getting invoked twice

Comment: Comment or delete the `read_scanner(txtbarcode.Text);` line in your `txtbarcode_KeyDown` method. Then run your program and try pressing enter again with the text box in focus and not in focus to see what happens.

Comment: `return true;` is missing.  Which indicates that you processed the command and the keystroke should not be used for anything else.

Comment: @HansPassant which method do i add return true?

Comment: ProcessCmdKey(), inside the if-statement.

Comment: @HansPassant if i return true the textbox is not accepting any letter as input when i type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ProcessCmdKey` is a virtual method on all `Forms` that listens to all keys and return `true` if it was a command key and `false` for other keys, so you might not need to implement `KeyDown` at all.

[documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey?view=netcore-3.1)

I've changed the code a little to make use of a `StringBuilder` and add the values to that `StringBuilder`.

```
StringBuilder _barcodeBuilder = new StringBuilder();
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{

    if (keyData != Keys.Return)
    {
        switch (keyData)
        {
            case Keys.NumPad0:
                _barcodeBuilder.Append(0);
                break;
            case Keys.NumPad1:
                _barcodeBuilder.Append(1);
                break;
            case Keys.NumPad2:
                _barcodeBuilder.Append(2);
                break;
            case Keys.NumPad3:
                _barcodeBuilder.Append(3);
                break;
            //and so on for the rest of the numpad keys
            default:
                _barcodeBuilder.Append((char)keyData);
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this, _barcodeBuilder.ToString());
        //read_scanner(_barcodeBuilder.ToString());
        textBox1.Clear();
        _barcodeBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    }
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

*Numpad* keys are a bit strange, so you can handle them with a switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

The source of your problem is unclear. Although if you want to track the source of what triggers your method, use `System.Environment.StackTrace` and output that as a debug message. You might have to use the "Debug" configuration for that.

Comment: The source trigger is the ProcessCmdKey

Comment: You said the method gets invoked twice, right? Your debug message should fire twice if the method it is in is invoked twice. If the stacktrace of both are identical, then you know it is indeed an issue with the trigger itself (which might be least likely). If you get only one stacktrace, it means the method is just invoked once. If you get two different stacktraces, it means you triggered your method accidentally over two different execution paths.